# Converting multiple columns from mysql recordset into Array

Tags: arrays, scala, iterator, recordset

In Scala 2.12, I am trying to convert two columns from a MySQL query into two arrays, before combining the two arrays into one as below

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://00.0.0.00:3306/dataanalysis"
val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val username = "xxxx"
val password = "yyyy"
var connection:Connection = _

  Class.forName(driver)

  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
  val statement = connection.createStatement
  val rs1 = statement.executeQuery("" +
    "select BBK,date_format(min(date(AAA)),'%Y%m%d') as AAA from OPER_MEMB_AAAD " +
    "where AAF between '2020/07/01' and '2020/07/31' " +
    "group by BBK order by BBK")

val strBBKArray=new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = rs1.next()
    def next() = rs1.getString(1)
 }.toArray

val strAAAArray=new Iterator[String] {
  def hasNext = rs1.next()
  def next() = rs1.getString(2)
}.toArray
```

val strRs1Array=Array(strBBKArray,strAAAArray)

It worked with column BBK but not AAA.

```
val strBBKArray: Array[String] = Array(1211212,2324324...
val strAAAArray: Array[String] = Array()
```

When I have strAAAArray filled with element before strBBKArray, column AAA is converted into an Array but no BBK. My guess is the iterator went to the bottom of rs1 for the first column and it found no more records when I wanted to iterate again. How can I get the iterator back to the first row of rs1 or there is a better way of converting a multi-column recordset into one Array?

Comment: You can read more about how Iterators in scala work and especially next() at the scala documentation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it this way. It worked although it is more complicated than I expected. If someone has a better solution. Feel free to post it and I will tick your answer after testing.

```
 val rs1 = statement.executeQuery("" +
    "select BBK,AAA from OPER_MEMB_AAAD order by BBK")

while (rs1.next()){
  strBBKArrayRs1+=rs1.getString(1)
  strAAAArrayRs1+=rs1.getString(2)
}

val rs2 = statement.executeQuery("" +
  "select BBK,AAB from MIDD_MEMB_AAAJ order by BBK")

while (rs2.next()){
  strBBKArrayRs2+=rs2.getString(1)
  strAAAArrayRs2+=rs2.getString(2)
}

val strRs1Array=ArrayBuffer(strBBKArrayRs1,strAAAArrayRs1)
val strRs2Array=ArrayBuffer(strBBKArrayRs2,strAAAArrayRs2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm getting totally confused here. But you know when you're doing next() you're actually removing elements from the iterator? If you want to iterative twice over it...maybe you could try create a copy of it before iterating over it. Then iterate over the second one? Or you could use other iteration than next()

```
  val rs1 = statement.executeQuery("" +
    "select BBK,date_format(min(date(AAA)),'%Y%m%d') as AAA from OPER_MEMB_AAAD " +
    "where AAF between '2020/07/01' and '2020/07/31' " +
    "group by BBK order by BBK")

val rs2 = rs1.clone

val strBBKArray=new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = rs1.next()
    def next() = rs1.getString(1)
 }.toArray

val strAAAArray=new Iterator[String] {
  def hasNext = rs2.next()
  def next() = rs2.getString(2)
}.toArray
```

You can read more about how Iterators in scala work and especially next() at the scala documentation: [docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html)

Otherwise, I'd personally use map instead or "toArray" if that exists. I don't know what's possible with the mysql recordset. Check the library and methods you have :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try to fine how to clone rs1. Look like clone is not a method accepted by rs1.

Comment: Then I'd just use a different method than using next :)